# Core Segmentation Fault With Vector

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

The following pertains to homework. Restraunt pet project type thing, task is to update it to use vectors. The issue I'm having is this:
This winds up causing a core segmentation fault, yet is able to retrieve all the information appropriately when I use valgrind.

```
void Table::partyCheckout(void)
{
        if(status == SERVED)
        {
                cout << " ---------------- " << endl;
                cout <<"Table: " << tableId << "\nParty Size: " << numPeople << "\nWaiter: " << waiter->getName() << "\nSummary: " <<endl;
                order->requestSummary();
                cout << "Total: " << endl;
                order->requestTotal();
                cout << " ---------------- " << endl;
                status = IDLE;
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "Error: " << tableId << " ";
                if(numPeople == 0)
                {
                        cout << "No one is at this table." << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                        cout << "This party hasn't been served." << endl;
                }
        }
}
```

Setup: I'm storing the waiters and the orders in vectors.
At runtime: when it does the waiter->getName() it complains that it's an invalid read, and that the memory location has been free'd by vector via a deallocater. 
My logic on the matter: It looks ahead and sees that the vector itself is not accessed again and so deallocates it. Since I do no more writing after this point, the memory location remains intact. When it tries to read the location it sees it has been free'd, hence invalid read but it still gets the appropriate data. 
So my question then, I suppose is two fold:
Does this logic sound right? 
What should I do to fix it?

```
#ifndef HW3_H
#define HW3_H
#include <vector>
#include "Table.h"
#include "Waiter.h"

class hw3
{
private:

        vector<Table> tables;
        vector<Waiter> waiters;
        vector<Order> orders;
public:
        void begin();

};
#endif
```

.cpp file, most of the allocation:

```
 ifstream configFile("config.txt"); //This guy is for initializing things
        string line;

        Menu theMenu;
        getline(configFile, line);
        stringstream intMaker;
        int t1;
        int t2;
        string temp;
        string temp2;
        string temp3;
        while (true)
        {
                getline(configFile, line);
                Tokenizer str(line, " \n");
                if(line =="")
                {


                        break;
                }
                else
                {
                        temp = str.next();
                        temp2 = str.next();
                        intMaker << temp;
                        intMaker >> t1;
                        intMaker.str("");
                        intMaker.clear();
                        intMaker << temp2;
                        intMaker >> t2;
                        intMaker.str("");
                        intMaker.clear();
                        tables.push_back(*(new Table(t1,t2)));


                }


        }

        getline(configFile, line);
        while (true)
        {
                getline(configFile, line);
                Tokenizer name(line, " ");
                string tabl = "";
                //Siphon off the name and the tables.
                temp = name.next();
                tabl = name.next();
                Tokenizer strink(tabl, ",\n");
                int numTables = (int) tables.size();
                Table * tabs[numTables];
                t1 = 0;
                int keepinTabs = 0;
                while(true)
                {
                        string temp2 = strink.next();

                        if (temp2 == "")
                        {

                                 break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                 intMaker << temp2;
                                 intMaker >> t1;

                                 intMaker.str("");
                                 intMaker.clear();
                                 for(int i = 0; i < numTables; i++)
                                 {
                                        if(tables.at(i).getTableId() == t1)
                                        {
                                                tabs[keepinTabs] = &tables.at(i);
                                        }
                                 }
                                 keepinTabs++;
                        }

                }

                waiters.push_back(*(new Waiter(temp, tabl, *tabs))); //Waiter(name, list of tables, and an array of table numbers.
                for(int j = 0; j < keepinTabs; j++)
                {
                        for(int i = 0; i < tables.size(); i++)
                        {
                                if(tabs[j]->getTableId() == tables[i].getTableId())
                                {
                                        tables.at(i).assignWaiter(&(waiters.back()));
                                }
                        }
                }
                if(line == "")
                {
                        break;
                }
        }
```

Comment: It would definitely help to see the vector-related code. :-)

Comment: Your current code fragment does not contain any obvious bugs, and your description of the issue does not give us enough to go on. This makes assiting you very hard! Have you stepped through this with a debugger? Is `waiter` an invalid pointer, or is it the `getName` method that is causing the error?

Comment: I'll see if I can't fit it.

Comment: Just a wild guess - I see some iterators (or pointers?) in your code - order. Maybe some erase operation invalidates your iterator?

Comment: `push_back(*new Table(...))`, et. al. These will cause memory leaks.  Since you're storing objects, no reason to dynamically allocate them, they will be copied into the `vector` appropriately.

Comment: Further to Chad's comment, you should either a) not allocate new `Table` objects on the heap, or b) use a `std::vector<Table*>` to store them in. Better yet, use `std::shared_ptr<Table>` instead of `Table*`.

Comment: Revising that to push_back(temp), or something of that nature?

Comment: Other possibly suspicious bits of code... the `Waiter` constructor, and `Tokenizer`. Care to share?

Comment: I'd be willing to, but the Tokenizer was supplied by the professor, so I hope that any issues with that are minimal. The Waiter constructor shouldn't be the source of the problem, it worked fine when I had this code with a bunch of dynamically allocated arrays instead of vectors. But I have no real qualms about sharing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues I can see:

```
tables.push_back(*(new Table(t1,t2)));
```

This code dynamically allocates an object of type `Table`, then pushes a **copy** of this object into `tables`, and then forgets the address of the dynamically allocated object - you're leaking memory.

```
waiters.push_back(*(new Waiter(temp, tabl, *tabs)));
```

As above, with `Waiter` this time.

```
tabs[keepinTabs] = &tables.at(i);
```

This takes the address of an object inside the vector. While legal, it's extremely fragile. `std::vector` can move its contents around in memory when it resizes (e.g. when you push into it).

This (or similar code elsewhere) might be the cause of your segfault. Seeing as you're allocating the objects dynamically, maybe you should declare your vectors to hold just pointers:

```
vector<Table*> tables;
vector<Waiter*> waiters;
vector<Order*> orders;
```

You would then do e.g. `tables.push_back(new Table(t1, t2));`. Of course, you have to make sure to `delete` the dynamically allocated objects when you remove them from the vectors. An alternative would be to use smart pointers, e.g.:

```
vector<std::shared_ptr<Table> > tables;
vector<std::shared_ptr<Waiter> > waiters;
vector<std::shared_ptr<Order> > orders;
```

Comment: That was it. Changing the vectors to vectors of pointers instead of vectors of things fixed my core segmentation faults. Thank you very much everyone who responded.